# How do I break out of this loop in bash

Tags: bash

I want to break out of this loop when grep doesn't match its pattern. The "higher" goals here were:

- see the output (stdout be unaffected)
- grep it for a pattern
- stop processing once a pattern is not found

.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ex
i=1
RERUN=0
while [ ${RERUN} == 0 ]
do
   ((i++))
   echo -n "Rerun${i}"| tee >(grep --color=always 'Rerun[123]' ; export RERUN=$?)
   echo ${RERUN}
   sleep 1
done
```

My guess why its not working is that is has to do with different shell levels

Comment: Correct, setting variables in a subshell doesn't change their value in the parent. `export` propagates values *down* the process tree, not up it.

Comment: BTW, `(( i++ ))` actually is a failure if `i=0` due to `set -e` (the unintuitiveness of this is among the reasons `set -e` is [considered extremely controversial](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) -- skip past the allegory and read the exercises if in a hurry).

Comment: ...now, you **can** get the exit status of a process substitution, but only if you're running bash 4.4; what version is this?

Comment: BTW, do you *really* want the string to be printed twice (once by `tee`, once by `grep`) when `grep` matches it?

Comment: BTW, the comparison operator is `=`, not `==` (the latter being a misguided attempt to protect programmers from script errors).

Comment: Yes and in color too ;) because this is my boiled down testscript. in the real one i have neither set -ex (read fail fast) nor grep without "-q"

Comment: my bash version is 4.4.12(1)-release but i'd rather be conservative (if possible)

Answer (score 1):

I might write this like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

generate_output() {
  local i=0
  while :; do
    (( ++i ))
    printf 'Rerun%s\n' "$i"
    sleep 1
  done
}

while IFS= read -r line; do
  printf '%s\n' "$line"
  [[ $line = Rerun[123] ]] || break
done < <(generate_output)
```

Note that there's no need to communicate between the two processes with a shared variable -- sending a SIGPIPE to `generate_output` by closing the file descriptor it's writing to suffices.

Comment: Hmm, it didn't cut the mustard for me but thanks anyway. i think I have a solution now

Comment: "Didn't cut the mustard" how? Does it fail? With what specific error?

Comment: (Checking, the test was inverted -- we were breaking *when we saw* `Test1`, `Test2` or `Test3` rather than when we saw anything but; edited to invert the logic while keeping the approach).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
# set -x
i=0
RERUN_FILE=$(mktemp)
declare -a TESTDATA=("run" "run" "run" "last" "run" "run" "run" )
while ! $(grep -q 1 ${RERUN_FILE})
do
   echo -n ${TESTDATA[$i]}| tee >(grep --color=always 'run'; echo -n $? >${RERUN_FILE})
   ((i++))
   sleep 1
done
rm ${RERUN_FILE} # do your dishes after the meal
```

Comment: Huh. `while ! $( command-that-emits-no-output )` is weird -- the `$()` runs the output of the command as a command itself (after string-splitting and glob expansion), but if you have no output it's a noop and so leaves the prior exit status alone.

Comment: ...btw, it's generally a bad idea to set up a pipeline (or run tools such as `tee` or `grep`) inside a loop. Subshells, external command invocations, &c. are expensive -- `grep` is much faster than a shell-builtin test *once it's running*, but the cost of starting it up (over and over, once per line you're evaluating) is high. (This is why it's generally a good idea to put such external commands *outside* your loop generating a continual stream of lines from just one instance, and then iterate over those lines using shell builtins only).

Comment: so, f/e, it'd be faster if you did `printf '\n' >"$RERUN_FILE"` to set the sigil, and use `while ! [ -s "$RERUN_FILE" ]` to wait for it to be set -- that way you're avoiding at least one `grep`. (As another aside: [POSIX requires](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) the shell and compliant OS utilities to exclusively use all-caps names for their own purposes and leave lowercase names for application use; using lowercase variable names in your own code thus prevents unintended conflicts).